# MySQL Match Against in HQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

since i can't find much documentation on HQL,   what I often do it look it up in MYSQL and about 75% of the times it works in HQL,   what I would like to do is enable text searching against a particular field in the db, being mindful of performance implications.   the mysql documentation say that the table structure must be MyiSam, and to create a fulltext index on that field.   and use a statement which in HQL would look something like this :

```
where match(product) against (:textinput)
```

Does anyone know if this is supported or whether HQL provides a more efficient way of doing such a thing?   thanks for your insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so let me answer my own questions based on my own findings. 
to answer my first question : whether (match/against) class supported in HQL

the answer is no this is still not supported.

other ways to achieve this:  this can be done by either creating a SQL query instance by calling

```
  session.createSQLQuery("") or by defining @NamedNativeQueries
```

have a look at the following example of  [@NamedNativeQuery](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/NamedNativeQuery.htm).